# Concurrent Consumers in Quarkus

Tags: spring-kafka, quarkus, kafka-consumer-api, quarkus-kafka

Is there a way to manage concurrency for concurrent consumers while trying  to consume messages from Quarkus?

I am looking for Batch Processing with concurrency to process several messages in seconds. I tried the same in SpringBoot earlier and it works ok. Trying to find a way if Quarkus is better.

Comment: At the moment, use @Blocking(ordered=false). The concurrency support got re-implemented and soon you will be able to configure the `concurrency` attribute on each connector (including kafka).

Answer (score 1):

Check the [SmallRye Reactive Messaging](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.3/model/model.html#processing-streams) tutorial and the [Kafka Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#receiving-kafka-records-in-batches).

Basically, you can either do batch processing in an imperative or reactive way.

Imperative way:

```java
@Incoming("your-topic")
public void handle(List<Message> messages) {
    // process
}
```

Reactive way:

```java
@Incoming("your-topic")
public Uni<Void> handle(Multi<Message> messages) {
    // process
}
```